# How to install Nuget package on Server without internet connection or local repo?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I have a build server that does not have internet access and I want to install [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild/10.0.61026) on it.

I have downloaded `nuget.exe` and copied it to the server and added it to my `PATH` and also copied the nuget package above to the server and tried to install with `nuget install microsoft.data.tools.msbuild.10.0.61026.nupkg`

But the install fails with

`Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org./v3/index.json.`

Is there a way to simply install a `nupkg` file without a repo? The server is Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Have you added the package source as your local directory to the NuGet.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the wrong folder when I ran the command. I needed to be one folder above and then specify the folder as the source. Worked.

`nuget install -source C:\NugetDownloads microsoft.data.tools.msbuild -OutputDirectory E:\Nuget`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using NuGet 3 since this used to work in NuGet 2.

Disabling all your online package sources should allow you to install a NuGet package locally.

So you can either change your %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config file so it has no package sources. Or you could use the -source parameter, specifying a package source that works offline, when calling install so the online package source is not used.

Comment: I tried both the -Source and -OutputDirectory parameters and I get a message saying "All packages listed in packages.config are already installed." But packages.config does not exist. I also tried your suggestion by removing the entry in the Nuget.Config file but I get the same message.

Comment: I just stumbled across this solution and it worked for me.  Our build server does not have an internet connection so the developers are responsible for downloading the most recent external libraries, packages, etc. and placing them on a network share (path specified in their references). So I removed all keys under <packageSources> and <activePackageSource> and the build went from 1 hour and 2 minutes to 1.5 minutes